# How to cycle only when date changes within array in twig?

Tags: php, twig

I am very new to twig and have a problem which I don't know how to solve.

So I have something like this:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
{% set startDate = entry.begin|date_time %}
% set endDate = entry.end|date_time %}

 <tr class="{{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) }}">
                <td class="text-nowrap">
                    {% block date_begin %}{{ entry.begin|date_time }}{% endblock %}
                    {% if entry.end %}
                        {% block date_end %}{{ endDatum }}{% endblock %}
                    {% endif %}
                </td>

{% endfor %}
```

If the entries have the same date I want the `<tr>` to get the same class, but how do I check if the startDate of Array.1 is the same of Array.2?

As I am not really experienced with twig I can't write much here.

Comment: Not sure why you are using a custom filter `date_time` as `twig` already has a built-in filter [`date`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html)

Comment: I don‘t really know, that code is part of the core from the used software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the function `cycle` for this use-case.

As you want to keep track of the `start_date` of a previous entry, you will need to store the date in a (temporary) variable and use that variable to toggle the class when they are not the same date.

```
{% set is_even = true %}
{% set current_date = null %}

<table>
{% for entry in entries %}
    {# store the first start_date in current_date so we can actually compare dates #}
    {% if current_date is null %}
        {% set current_date = entry.start_date %}
    {% endif %}
    
    {# toggle the class when the dates aren't the same #}
    {% if current_date|date('U') != entry.start_date|date('U') %}
        {% set is_even = not is_even %}   
        {% set current_date = entry.start_date %}
    {% endif %}
    
    <tr class="{{ is_even ? 'even':'odd' }}">
        <td class="text-nowrap">
            {{ entry.start_date }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/tqqkr1)

Comment: Thank you for your Help, that works fine for the odd and even.
In my case i already do this with php but twig is another thing ;)
I ran an foreach where i stored all dates and then checked with the index.
thats what i needed for the summery of durations.

is there any chance to do this in twig?
 for example

 <tr class="{{ is_even ? 'even':'odd' }}">
        <td class="text-nowrap">
            {{ entry.start_date }}
        </td>
    </tr>
if(!sameDate){
echo "tablerow - with summery";
}

Comment: i just found a solution:

https://twigfiddle.com/tqqkr1/2